# Solve $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{x-1}^{x+1}{f(t)}dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Let $f(x)\in\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{R})$,$\inf\lim\limits_{|x|\to\infty}{f(x)}=0$(that is $\inf\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}{f(x)}=0$ and $\inf\lim\limits_{x\to-\infty}{f(x)}=0$), such that

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{x-1}^{x+1}{f(t)}dt$$

Prove that:

$$f(x)\equiv 0,\  x\in\mathbb{R}$$

**My attempt**

I try to solve this equation, but I have trouble in it. Obviously, $f(x)= ax + b$ satisfies the equation. However, I don't know how to deal with the general case.

I want to get some help. Thanks.

Comment: First thought, possible hint: the right hand side is differentiable, so $f$ is, so try the fundamental theorem of calculus to get a differential equation for $f$,

Comment: I thought that stuff was easy but...

Comment: [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) may help. So differentiating on both sides, we get $2f'(x)=f(x+1)-f(x-1)$. Now we need solve this functional equation.

Comment: No taking Limit on both sides as $x$ goes to infinity, RHS becomes zero (by the given condition) and so that we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} f'(x)=0$. Does this imply $f(x)=0$?

Comment: @ProblemBook We aren't given the limit at $-\infty$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog In my mean, the $\lim_{x\to\infty}{f(x)}=0$ is equal to $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}{f(x)}=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer to the edited question.** As for the edited question which assumes $f(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$, the equation is essentially a version of Laplace equation (and is indeed the Laplace equation corresponding to some discrete-time diffusion process, see below), and so, we can borrow various fancy ideas in the theory of harmonic functions. (I strongly recommend to read **@clark**'s now-deleted answer, if you have enough reputation to see deleted answers.)

Just for fun, let me present a solution using a bit of probability theory. Let $(X_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $X_n \sim \mathrm{Uniform}([-1,1])$ and $S_n = X_1 + \cdots + X_n$ be its partial sum. Then the assumption translates to $ f(x) = \mathbf{E}[f(x+X_1)] $, hence

$$ f(x) = \mathbf{E}[f(x + S_n)] $$

for any $n$. Since $f(x) \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$, $f$ is bounded and let $M \geq 0$ be a bound of $f$. Moreover, for any fixed $t > 0$, we know from Central Limit Theorem that $\mathbf{P}(|S_n| \leq t) \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$. So it follows that

\begin{align*}
|f(x)|
&= \mathbf{E}[|f(x+S_n)|\mathbf{1}_{\{|S_n| \leq t\}}] + \mathbf{E}[|f(x+S_n)|\mathbf{1}_{\{|S_n| > t\}}] \\
&\leq M \mathbf{P}(|S_n| \leq t) + \left( \sup_{|x-x'| > t} |f(x')| \right).
\end{align*}

Taking limsup as $n\to\infty$ followed by $t\to\infty$, we obtain $|f(x)| \leq 0$ and therefore $f \equiv 0$.

---

**Answer to the original question.** Only under the condition $\lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x) = 0$, there are indeed non-trivial solutions originating from delay-differential equation.

Let $\alpha$ be a non-zero solution of $\alpha = \sinh \alpha$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\operatorname{Re}(\alpha) < 0$. (It is easy to check that there is no pure-imaginary solution except for zero. So if $\alpha \neq 0$ solves the equation, then so does $-\alpha$ and one of $\alpha$ or $-\alpha$ has negative real-part. The existence of such solution is not hard to prove. One such zero is numerically given as $-2.76868 + 7.49768 i$.) Then set

$$ f(x) = \operatorname{Re}(e^{\alpha x}). $$

Since $|f(x)| \leq |e^{\alpha x}| = e^{\operatorname{Re}(\alpha)x} \to 0$ as $x \to +\infty$, we know that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to +\infty$. Moreover,

$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{x-1}^{x+1}f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Re}\left[ \int_{x-1}^{x+1} e^{\alpha t} \, \mathrm{d}t \right]
= \operatorname{Re}\left[ \frac{\sinh(\alpha)}{\alpha} e^{\alpha x} \right]
= f(x). $$

Therefore $f$ satisfies all the assumptions in the original question but is not identically zero.

Comment: @SangchuiLee emmm..I want to get an elementary proof.Could you please give me a proof with real analysis method?

Comment: @SangchuiLee And It's $\inf \lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=0$,not $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=0$.

Comment: @LiTaichi, Well, the assumption in OP was $\lim_{|x|\to\infty} f(x) = 0$ at the point I wrote up the answer, but it is edited later. I feel it's unfair to blame my answer for that. (Silently editing the question after people have posted answers renders their answers less adequate, which I think is a bit embarrassing. Who would feel happy when they later find their answers became a nonsense to the edited version of the question? Perhaps you can mention edit history in OP to prevent this.) Also, do you mean $\liminf_{|x|\to\infty} f(x) = 0$? I have never seen a notation like $\inf\lim$ before...

Comment: @SangchuiLee I don't mean to blame you. emmm..I don't want to edit the problem. I think that the $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$ is equal to $\lim_{|x|\to\infty}f(x)=0$,but when I see comments,I realize my mistakes.So I edted my question.If you feel offended, I am very sorry for that

Comment: @SangchuiLee How to prove that there exists non-zero solution for $\sinh z =z$？It is not easy.

Answer (score 5):

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then $$\left|\frac{1}{2}\int_{x-1}^{x+1}f(x)dx\right| \le \frac{1}{2}2\sup_{t \in [x-1,x+1]}|f(t)|$$
with equality iff $f$ is constant throughout $[x-1,x+1]$.

Suppose $f$ is not identically zero. Then $\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}}|f(x)| > 0$, and this maximum is attained (since $f(x) \to 0$), at some $\xi$ say. WLOG $f(\xi) > 0$. Then we have:

$$\sup_{t \in [\xi-1,\xi+1]}|f(t)| = f(\xi) \ge \frac{1}{2}\int_{\xi-1}^{\xi+1}f(t)dt$$
so $f$ is constant on $[\xi-1,\xi+1]$. By induction, $f$ is constant on $[\xi-n,\xi+n]$ for all $n$, and choosing $n$ large enough shows that this constant must be $0$.

EDIT: This isn't quite complete - I've realised the OP only says $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ and not necessarily as $x \to -\infty$. Not obvious to me how to patch it yet.

Patch: By the argument above, we certainly have a $\xi$ which maximises $f$ on $[0,\infty)$. It follows that $f$ is constant and equal to zero on $[0,\infty)$. But then we can go backwards and get that $f$ is constant on $[-1,1]$, and $[-2,0]$, and $[-3,-1]$, and so on... So $f$ must be identically zero.

Edit 2: As @clark points out, this argument is still not complete.

Comment: Yes, had the same problem with my answer.

Comment: Okay, I *think* the updated argument is sound.

Comment: What if the $\xi$ that maximizes $f$ on $[0,\infty)$ is at $0$, but $\xi$ is just a local maximum. Then how to apply the previous argument, since the integral $\int_{\xi-1}^{\xi+1}$ will use values outside $[0,\infty)$

Comment: @clark Conceded, I'll re-mark the answer as incomplete

Comment: I think we can't get the max value in $\mathbb{R}$.@preferred_anon

Comment: Oh! The question's changed. Do you mean $\lim \inf $?